# Cross Validation folds in LibSVM

Tags: svm, cross-validation, libsvm

how the folds in cross validation of libSVM are done?, I mean, the splits are done aleatory? for example if I have 100 data and it is 4-fold then when it is an aleatory folding then can be splited like this?

- 20-45 : fold1
- 45-70 : fold2
- 70-95 : fold3
- 95-20 : fold4

or it make the folds always starting from the first one:

- 1-25   : fold1
- 25-50  : fold2
- 50-75  : fold3
- 75-100 : fold4

so how can I choose which kind on folding I want to use?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Wow, I love the word "aleatory".

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the way folds are generated in cross-validation. In cross-validation, your data set is partitioned *at random* into a specific number of folds.<sup>*</sup> The data is not partitioned as you would slice a pie (e.g. adjacent instances belonging to the same fold).

<sup>*</sup>: in *stratified* cross-validation the class balance in the overall data set is maintained across folds.

Comment: While randomly assigning the cases to the folds is usually the best option, there are systematic ways of spitting which are also discussed as "cross validation" see e.g. here wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=Using_Cross-Validation.